# Simple Initial Value Integral: Two Methods, Two Different Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

"Find $y(x)$ to satisfy $y' = (x-2)^2$,  $y(2) = 1$"

**My Work:**

So, this takes on the form:

$\int dy = \int (x-2)^2dx$

I then try solving via $u = x-2$, and get:

$y = \frac{(x-2)^3}{3} + C \to$ $1 = \frac{(2-2)^3}{3} + C \to C = 1 \therefore y = \frac{(x-2)^3}{3} + 1$

This is the *only* answer given in my book. However, I originally did the integral by expanding $(x-2)^2$, which I usually prefer to do if all the expanded integrals will be very simple. By that, I get:

$\int dy = \int (x^2 - 4x + 4)dx$

When solved:

$y = \frac{x^3}{3} - 2x^2 + 4x + C \to 1 = \frac{2^3}{3} - 2(2)^2 + 4(2) + C \to$

$1 = \frac{8}{3} - 8 + 8 + C \to C = \frac{-5}{3} \therefore y = \frac{x^3}{3} - 2x^2 + 4x -\frac{5}{3}$

So the same simple integral, when expanded, gives a totally different value for C. Is this valid? If not, what have I done wrong that leads to this result?

Comment: your mistake is that you forgot to distribute the 3 to all terms.

Comment: Which 3 are you referring to?

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong except to expect the constant of integration to be unchanged by your substitution - note that your expressions for $y$ are equivalent

Comment: $$\frac{(x-2)^{3}}{3} + 1 = \frac{x^{3} - 6x^{2} + 12x - 8}{3} + 1 = \frac{x^{3}}{3} - 2x^{2} + 4x -\frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: Okay, this was what I was thinking, but I was worried that my book provided a single answer as if it were *the* answer. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two different methods lead you to find two different constants, $c_1$ and $c_2$. That's not wrong - there are in fact infinitely many general solutions to this differential equation. That's why you need to specify an initial value condition, to nail down *one particular* solution.

In this case, your integration-by-substitution carries over an extra constant term, $\frac{-8}{3}$, which is basically just a parallel shift of the expression for the general solution.

What matters is your particular solution - the specific solution satisfying the initial value condition $y(2)=1$. That is, the equation you will get *after* you substitute in the relevant constants you found. You should try continuing your two methods of solution to their conclusion by doing this.

In both methods, you should find that the particular solution will be the same:

$y_p = \frac{x^3}{3}-2x^2+4x-\frac{5}{3}$.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your two answers at four different values for x, and they were the same in each case.  Since they are both cubic polynomials, they must be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions are exactly equal, and the second is just the expansion of the first one. Try it!